# In a WPF combobox is it wise to use a string type value as the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml, combobox

Following on from [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301165/should-i-design-a-table-with-a-primary-key-of-varchar-or-int) about primary keys I am wondering if there is a performance impact in using a string value as the key in WPF comboboxes.  For example

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TestCB" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" DisplayMemberPath="ProductName" 
                  SelectedValuePath="ShortCode" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedProduct.ShortCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

As ShortCode and SelectedProduct.ShortCode are of type ***string***, would it be slower to find the SelectedItem when the source changes as opposed to having an ***int*** such as ProductID.  If so, what is the logic behind this i.e. no full text indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have millions of items in your combobox (which would be awful for the user experience), I don't think it will have a significant impact on performance... Comparisons on short strings are fast, even though not as fast as integer comparisons...