# ASP.NET Identity update column type for primary key Id in AspNetUsers table from a string to and int or a guid, yes or no?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Today I read about the new features in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 alpha.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx

Apparently the possibility to use and `int` or a `guid` as the primary key for the `AspNetUsers` table was added after numerous post/questions on stackoverflow.

I started using ASP.NET Identity when the RTM was announced. Since then I have been using the default `string` (`nvarchar(128)`) type for the `Id` column in the `AspNetUsers` table.

I want my app to be **futureproof**. So what I'm wordering is wheather or not I should follow the instructions in these new documents on how to change your `Id` column to and `int` or a `guid`.

What is the most appropriate for an e-commerce site?

What is the most appropriate for a regular site?

When to use what?

**Update 1**:

Already found one good thing about using an `int` while testing `PrimaryKeysConfigTest` *WebForms* sample app (https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest Samples->Identity->ChangePK->PrimaryKeysConfigTest). When updating the table `AspNetUserRoles` manually in SQL Server Object Explorer you don't need to copy paste the long guid-string into the `UserId` and `RoleId` columns. You remember them by heart.

**Update 2**:

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest Samples->Identity->Identity-PasswordPolicy->Identity-PasswordPolicy is an *MVC* application and uses a `nvarchar(128)` for the `Id` column in `AspNetUsers` table. If you're looking to implement the new user account confirmation/forgot password features in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 alpha for an MVC application then this is the sample app you should look at.

Comment: The de facto standard for a primary key is an integer. In my experience using GUIDs just lead to more headache than they are worth. Here's a link to a more thorough exploitation. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301165/should-i-design-a-table-with-a-primary-key-of-varchar-or-int/1301536#1301536)

Comment: If so then maybe the default should be an int for a default MVC 5 web app? I wonder what the MVC / Identity team has to say about this!?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553424/how-to-change-type-of-id-in-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityus/19577113#19577113) may answer _why_.